# CUPS @LOCAL value

Tags: local, broadcast, discovery, cups

I got two machines. One with CUPS 1.5.0 and the other with CUPS 1.6.1. The two machines are on the same local network. I want a full discovery of the printers on the network. If i run the following command:

```
CUPS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 /usr/lib/cups/backend/snmp 2>&1
```

on both machines i get different results. The one with CUPS 1.5.0 is the result i want from the other machine with CUPS 1.6.1 too.

I figured out the problem! There is a variable called `@LOCAL` in CUPS. The upper command equals with:

```
CUPS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 /usr/lib/cups/backend/snmp @LOCAL 2>&1
```

The problem is that in the second case (CUPS 1.6.1) the value of the `@LOCAL` is the local IP(192.168.3.69) of the machine instead of the broadcast(192.168.3.255).

If i run the following command on machine two all works perfectly:

```
CUPS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 /usr/lib/cups/backend/snmp 192.168.3.255 2>&1
```

Please explain me how can i configure the value of the `@LOCAL` variable. Or why does CUPS 1.5.0 configure it well on install and 1.6.1 don't? (I did not do anything after installing, and it worked perfectly)

Comment: UPDATE: With ifconfig i got that the Broadcast on the first machine was 192.168.3.255 while on the other machine it was 0.0.0.0 Obvoius now that it is a network configuration issue. I edited the broadcast on the second machine and it works now. But one question still remains: Why do i have to configure the broadcast on the second machine while not on the first one? To be more specific on the machines: The first's distribution is a debian squeeze and the second one is a debian wheezy. Both with static ip settings, but as i see there is no setting for broadcast in the squeeze.

Answer (score 4):

### First...

**...let's get clear what *`@LOCAL`* means:**

The `@LOCAL` string is not exactly a variable -- in the context of CUPS configuration (*/etc/cups/cupsd.conf*) it's called a *macro*. There are more macros that could be used: `@IF`, `@GROUP`, `@ACL`, `@OWNER` and `@SYSTEM`.

The `@LOCAL` macro was introduced into CUPS with version 1.1.15. The respective CHANGELOG entry reads:

> ```
>  - The Allow, Deny, BrowseAllow, BrowseDeny, and
>    BrowseAddress directives now support the network
>    interface names "@LOCAL" and "@IF(name)" for access
>    control and browsing based on the current interface
>    addresses instead of fixed names or IP addresses.
> ```

In other words: before its introduction into the CUPS code base, you had to hard-code the current IP addresses of the host into `cupsd.conf`. Afterwards, you had the option to just instead write `@LOCAL` or `@IF(eth0)` or `@IF(wlan1)` in `cupsd.conf` and CUPS would use the current IP address (***all*** the local IP addresses, if the box has multiple!) even if it changed. (Addresses for PPP/dialup connections don't count as local IP addresses...)

### Second...

**...let's see why you may see differences:**

Without access to your full CUPS and network device configuration of both of your two machines it is not possible to answer the question.

It *may* be the case that one server has more network interfaces and/or more different IP addresses than the other (like using the `eth0:1` trick to use an additional virtual network interface).

You *may* also have stumbled over a bug in one of the two CUPS incarnations of you machines.